# Postgresql trigger and trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have created 6 tables :- A, B, C, D, E & F where A is the parent table. Now I want to create a trigger to insert the data in table F after successful insertion of data in tables A, B, C, D & E. Also the data in F should contain the values from table A(so basically the trigger should be made for Table A).

In addition to that a column in table F is json. So i need to combine 3 columns from table A(which is character varying) and insert into json field of table F.
The data in json should appear like column name : value

Please suggest me the right approach.

Comment: You cannot have a trigger depend on events in multiple tables. Perhaps you can describe this in some more detail. Could it be that F should really be a view?

Comment: Yes true, but what if we insert the data in all 5 tables and only after commit the trigger gets fired on table A. Does postgres allow something like that?

Comment: Sure, you can define a constraint trigger as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)), and it will be run at transaction commit.

Comment: okay, thanks and how should I deal with json?

Comment: You can use the JSON creation functions described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE).

Comment: Can you please explain through demo like if i want to fetch the value from 3 columns(character varying) of Table A and store the value in table F(in json column) using trigger function?

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to read the documentation yourself.